# Las cadenas leídas desde un archivo no se guardan en mi arreglo

Tags: c, string, archivo, array

Pues verán, estoy intentando leer cadenas y quiero guardarlas en un arreglo, lo que estoy intentando leer del archivo es:

```
104 Victor Valdez M 2 soltero 0 160
105 Braulio Guerrero M 8 divorciado 2 172
106 Frida Corona F 1 soltero 0 160
107 Oscar Rodriguez M 15 casado 4 165
108 Alberto Ruiz M 1 soltero 0 160
109 Pedro Niño M 5 soltero 1 160
110 Karla Martinez F 5 casado 1 160
111 Carlos Contreras M 8 soltero 2 162
112 Juan Mata M 6 soltero 0 160
113 Tania Perez F 2 soltero 0 160
114 Ulises Juarez M 32 viudo 5 160
115 Brenda Galindo F 1 soltero 0 160
116 Luis Mora M 3 soltero 0 160
117 Cristobal Fernandez M 4 soltero 0 160 
118 Salvador Vallejo M 3 soltero 0 160
```

El código siguiente es lo que hago para leerlo:

```
int a, b, c;
    char caracteres[150], nEmp[100][150]; //nEmp es un arreglo que utilizare luego para separar las cadenas y guardarlas en su respectivo campo en una estructura
    FILE *fP = fopen("Empleados/Prueba15.txt", "rt"); //Archivo que estoy leyendo
for(a = 0 ; a < 15 ; a++){
        fgets(caracteres 150, fP);
        strcpy(nEmp[a], caracteres); //Copiar lo que leí en el archivo y guardarlo en nEmp[]
        puts(nEmp[a]); //Prueba para ver si efectivamente se guardó toda la cadena en nEmp[]
        system("pause");
    }
```

La salida esperada del programa debería de ser la lista ya mencionada, pero en vez de eso lo que obtengo de salida es:

```
       0
    Presione una tecla para continuar...
       0
    Presione una tecla para continuar...
       0
    Presione una tecla para continuar...
       0
    Presione una tecla para continuar...
```

Y así hasta acabar el ciclo, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No compruebas para nada los errores... ¿estás seguro que el fichero se abre, la línea se lee, etc..?  Deberías comprobar si `fp` o lo que devuelve `fgets` es `NULL`, lo que indicaría dónde está el problema

Comment: Adicional a lo que dice @SJuan76, deberias cambiar el delimitador de tu archivo, el espacio es, sencillamente malo para estas tareas.

Answer (score 1):

he estado echando un ojo a tu codigo y he encontrado algunos fallos y los he mejorado, para empezar no validas que el fihcero se haya abierto correctamente con lo cual he añadido esa validacion. Lo segundo el nombre del archivo no es correcto dado que el caracter "/" no puedes ponerlo en el nombre asi que lo he cambiado a EmpleadosPrueba15.txt. Una vez cambiado eso, es mejor que cambies el bucle for por un while para que lea hasta que encuentre el final del fichero para que no se quede ningun dato sin leer. Una vez hecho todo eso el codgio quedaria mas o menos asi:

> ```
> int a = 0, b, c; //Inicializamos la variable a = 0 desde el inicio
>
> char caracteres[150], nEmp[100][150]; //nEmp es un arreglo que utilizare luego para separar las cadenas y guardarlas en su respectivo
> campo en una estructura
> FILE *fP= fopen("EmpleadosPrueba15.txt", "rt"); //Archivo que estoy leyendo
>
> if(fP == NULL)      //Comprueba que se ha abierto el archivo correctamente
> {
>     printf("\nError, no se ha podido abir el archivo");
>     getchar();
>     exit(1);
> }
>
>     while(!feof(fP))        //Realizas el bucle hasta que llega al final del fichero, asi te aseguras de que no quede ninguna linea sin
> leer
> {
>     fgets(caracteres, 150, fP);     //La funcion fgets coge toda la cadena de caracteres incluyendo el \n que hay al final de la linea
>  con lo cual vamos a eliminarlo manualmente
>     caracteres[strlen(caracteres) - 1] = 0;    // Eliminamos el \n del final de linea antes de copiarla al arreglo
>     strcpy(nEmp[a], caracteres); //Copiar lo que leí en el archivo y guardarlo en nEmp[]
>
>     puts(nEmp[a]); //Prueba para ver si efectivamente se guardó toda la cadena en nEmp[]
>     a = a + 1;   //Aumentamos manualmente el contador
> }
> ```

Otra cosa que cambiaria seria todo el tema de las constantes que usas las de 100 y 150 yo lo haria con un #Define para que te quede el codigo mas limpio. Espero haberte ayudado